# Superset for Clickhouse in docker with SQLAlchemy

Tags: docker, sqlalchemy, clickhouse, apache-superset

I'm trying to setup Apache Superset for Clickhouse.
My understanding so far is that I need to install SQLAlchemy for Clickhouse
https://github.com/xzkostyan/clickhouse-sqlalchemy

I'm in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, and using the Docker vanilla version of Clickhouse and of Superset:

- https://store.docker.com/community/images/yandex/clickhouse-server
- https://hub.docker.com/r/amancevice/superset/

without special settings

Any idea how I can bridge the two docker containers with clickhouse-sqlalchemy ?
Where and how in that case to install that?
(if you have sample command line that I can reuse that will be great)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to bridge them: what you want is a superset server (that you happen to be running via docker) to connect to a clickhouse database (that you also happen to be running via docker).

You also shouldn't need to install SQLAlchemy for Clickhouse: looking at the dockerfile at https://hub.docker.com/r/amancevice/superset/~/dockerfile/ that image has already `sqlalchemy-clickhouse` installed for you.

Your steps should be as follow:

- When you `docker run --detach --name superset [options] amancevice/superset` you should have your superset instance running at http://localhost:8088/
- Similarly, when you run `$ docker run -d --name some-clickhouse-server --ulimit nofile=262144:262144 -v /path/to/your/config.xml:/etc/clickhouse-server/config.xml yandex/clickhouse-server` you should end-up with a clickhouse instance that you can access via SQLAlchemy at *something like* `clickhouse://default:@some-clickhouse-server/test`
  You'd need to modify that connection URI based on your config.xml - and you should be able to double-check that it works by connecting to it in your python console.
- You should then be able to connect superset to your clickhouse db in the same way you'd connect to any other DB: by navigating into Superset's menu > Sources > Databases > [new]

Comment: Hi, it work as you described (just for super set I had to check the IP with "docker inspect superset" and use that for the web access host name. Thank You !

Answer (score 0):

Consider using already prepared and configured *docker-compose.yml* which included in Apache Superset (see https://github.com/apache/superset/blob/master/docker-compose.yml).

To work with Clickhouse should be installed sqlalchemy driver. There are two ones:

- [clickhouse-sqlalchemy](https://github.com/xzkostyan/clickhouse-sqlalchemy) by xzkostyan
- [sqlalchemy-clickhouse](https://github.com/cloudflare/sqlalchemy-clickhouse) by cloudflare.

I recommend using [clickhouse-sqlalchemy](https://github.com/xzkostyan/clickhouse-sqlalchemy) because it is actually supported and evolute, it supports both available protocols to interact with ClickHouse - [HTTP](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/interfaces/http/) and [TCP](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/interfaces/tcp/) (native protocol).

---

Let's connect to one of the public ClickHouse:

- either *Demo Yandex CH*

```sh
docker run -it --rm yandex/clickhouse-client:latest \
    --host gh-api.clickhouse.tech --user explorer -s
```

- or *[Demo Altinity.Cloud CH](https://altinity.com/blog/connecting-to-altinity-cloud-with-the-clickhouse-web-ui)*

```sh
docker run -it --rm yandex/clickhouse-client:latest \
    --host github.demo.trial.altinity.cloud -s --user demo --password demo
```

---

1. download source code from repo https://github.com/apache/superset
2. execute the commands

```sh
cd superset-master

docker-compose up

# open the new terminal

docker-compose exec superset bash /app/docker/docker-init.sh
docker-compose exec superset pip install clickhouse-sqlalchemy
docker-compose restart
```

3. wait for containers to be started and the web app to be built (see the console output, *webpack* should finish its work)
4. browse URL *http://localhost:8088* (use credentials *admin* / *admin*)
5. add the database using one of the connection string:

```sh
# connection string for Demo Yandex ClickHouse
clickhouse+native://explorer@gh-api.clickhouse.tech/default?secure=true

# connection string for Demo Altinity.Cloud CH
clickhouse+native://demo:demo@github.demo.trial.altinity.cloud/default?secure=true
```

---

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/66006784/303298.

Comment: In the connection string, it is possible to pass alt_hosts as query params. Like this clickhouse+native://username:password@host:port/default?alt_hosts=host1:port1,host2:port2.

The following thing works fine for clickhouse://username:password@host:port/default, but I am getting an error will using clickhouse+native in the superset version 1.0.1 and unable to pass params.

Comment: @ANILPATEL you can't do that -  [clickhouse-sqlalchemy](https://github.com/xzkostyan/clickhouse-sqlalchemy) doesn't support this feature. You can ask for implement this feature here [feature request](https://github.com/xzkostyan/clickhouse-sqlalchemy/issues) or use [CH load balancer](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/interfaces/third-party/proxy/#proxy-servers-from-third-party-developers).